# How to load multiple js files to database using mongo shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have several `js` files with `collections` creations and seeds. I load data from one of them using, for example,

```
mongo <host>:<port>/<database> -u <user> -p <password> < db.users.js
```

However, now I have several files, and I wish I could load all of them to `mongo` using one command. Hopefully, with `mongo` shell.

Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: You could combine all js files into one js file.

Comment: Within `mongo` shell: You can create an array of the js file names. Then use the `load()` to run the js scripts in a loop, e.g., `for (let file of jsfiles) load(file)`.

Comment: From the command line you can specify more than one file, e.g.:  `mongo localhost/test script1.js script2.js`

Comment: @mhery can you please post the contents of db.users.js?

Comment: @user2243747, this file could have any mongo db method. in my project, this file right now just have `db.createCollection('users')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different ways to load (run) these files. I have two js files `script1.js` and `script2.js`, for example.

From **OS command line** specify all the files:

```
mongo localhost/testdb script1.js script2.js
```

Or, create one js file and include all the scripts. For example, create a `script_combined.js` with the following:

```
load("script1.js")
load("script2.js")
```

Run as:

```
mongo localhost/testdb script_combined.js
```

Alternative way to run multiple scripts from within **`mongo` shell**:

```
> const script_files = [ "script1.js", "script2.js" ]
> for (let file of script_files) {
      load(file)
  }
```