# MongoDb import JSON data to collection using redirection operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have set up `mongo' DB on my machine using the following docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/data:/usr/src/data
```

Now, I want to insert sample data into a collection named `books` using the below command

`mongo books < booksJson.js`

But when I execute this command I am getting the following error

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/books?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("57936227-aa22-4d5f-841b-59788847bc3c") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.1
WriteCommandError({
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "command insert requires authentication",
        "code" : 13,
        "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
})
bye
```

Below are the contents of my `booksJson.js` file.

```
db.books.insert([
{
     title: 'xyz',
     test: 1
}
])
```

**Any pointers towards how to use `mongo.exe` to import JSON data using a JavaScript file and redirection operator?**

Comment: I think you have to tell mongo which database you want to insert and add credentials for that db. for example: `mongo --db library -u username -p password books < booksJson.js`

Comment: See this post for: [How to load multiple js files using mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64001464/how-to-load-multiple-js-files-to-database-using-mongo-shell/64003009#64003009).

Comment: @Mahan it looks like --db option is not valid.  getting error : `Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--db'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Prasad's comment/pointer helped to find out the solution.

I was able to import data using the following command.

```
mongo localhost:27017/bookdb  --authenticationDatabase "admin" -u root -p example  < booksJson.js
```

I have to mention `authinticationDatabase` flag in order to get it to work.